# Sum of array including a function - C

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, sum, function-definition

I am a bit of a noob in programming, that is why I am struggling with this rather simple code.
Our task is to sum up all elements of an array using a function.
The function should print out the array, then sum up its elements and give back its sum to the main.
There it should be printed.
It is working until it gets to the function, I think.

Read a lot of other posts regarding this question but still can't wrap my head around the solution.
My compiler is also telling me "Segementation fault (core dumped)". I am really confused.

That's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 9           // i think the math one is a bit unneccessary but well

int sum(int array[], int size)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%d", array[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= MAX; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int array[MAX];
    int size;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        printf("\nGeben Sie die %d. Zahl ein: ", i);      // Its in german, basically saying the user should fill the array, starting with the 1. element
        scanf("%d", &array[i - 1]);
    }
    sum(array[MAX], size);
    printf("%d", size);
    return 0;
}
```

Helping me would be really nice.
Thanks!

Comment: If you have an array with MAX elements then valid indices are 0 - MAX-1.

Comment: `for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)` -> `for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)`. Better still use more standard 0 based counter: `for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) scanf("%d", &array[i]);`

Comment: @sam3004 Your function does not use the parameter size and the passed argument size is not initialized.

Comment: `sum(array[MAX], size);` -> `sum(array, size);`. The compiler should give you a warning about that as the types are incompatible. Always take note of the warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have it clear in mind that the last element of an array declared with `MAX` elements is the `MAX-1`-th because elements start from 0.

For example, the elements of `int array[3]` are: `array[0]`, `array[1]` and `array[2]`.

Now you understand that your loops should be

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
```

Because in case of `i == MAX` you would try to access `array[MAX]` which is not part of your array.

If `MAX` is 9, the last element is `array[8]` so `for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++)` should be

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
```

But it's better to use `MAX` instead of 9, so that if you want to make your program to work for an array of 20 elements you have to modify only the value of `MAX` and not all the piece of code where you wrote `9`

Now coming to the function call `sum(array[MAX], size);` it should be

```
sum(array, size);
```

To pass an array you have to pass the address of its first element, that is `&array[0]` or even just `array`. [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/14170686)

Then the `size` you passed is uninitialised and you don't even use it in `sum()`, so there's no no reason to declare it.

Also I noticed that you wanted to print `size` at the end and since you passed it to `sum()`, maybe you wanted to modify its value into the `sum()` function. If that's the case, then simply passing `size` is not enough. This would pass a copy of `size` and any change to its value would be lost (unless you return it, but you are already returning `sum`). To really modify `size` you have to pass its address `&size`, and have `sum()` receiving a pointer to int `int *`

```
int sum(int array[], int *size)
```

And also you return `sum` but don't store it anywhere. You should store it somewhere like

```
newVariable = sum(array, size);
```

Or if you just want to print it, then just print it

```
printf("%d", sum(array, size));
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens because array elements go from `0` to `MAX - 1`. By looping from `0` to `MAX` (included) you're asking your program to access up to the 11th element (`array[10]`).

Bonus: your call to the function should be `sum(array, size)` and you could use a single loop instead of two:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    printf("\n%d", array[i]);
    sum = sum + array[i]; // Same as sum += array[i];
}
```

`<math.h>` is indeed unnecessary here and you didn't use `<stdlib.h>` nor the parameter `size`, so you can safely remove them.

Comment: I was worrying about `size` not being initialised, without noticing that it is ignored, well spotted. (Strictly it still is undefined behaviour I think.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array with `MAX` elements then the valid range of indices is `[ 0, MAX )`.

The function `sum` does not use the parameter `size` and the passed argument `size` was not initialized.

Moreover the first parameter of the function call

```
sum(array[MAX], size);
```

has the type `int` instead of `int *`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 9

long long int sum( const int array[], size_t size )
{
    long long int total = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; i++ )
    {
        total += array[i];
        printf( "%d ", array[i] );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    return total;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int array[MAX];
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < MAX; i++ )
    {
        printf("Geben Sie die %zu. Zahl ein: ", i + 1 );
        scanf( "%d", array + i );
    }
    
    printf( "%lld\n", sum( array, MAX ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Geben Sie die 1. Zahl ein: 1
Geben Sie die 2. Zahl ein: 2
Geben Sie die 3. Zahl ein: 3
Geben Sie die 4. Zahl ein: 4
Geben Sie die 5. Zahl ein: 5
Geben Sie die 6. Zahl ein: 6
Geben Sie die 7. Zahl ein: 7
Geben Sie die 8. Zahl ein: 8
Geben Sie die 9. Zahl ein: 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
45
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a function sum to scan the elements of the array and I summed the elements of array

```
    scanf("%d", &array[i - 1]);
```

if You want to fill the array from the SIZE-1 to 0 ,just reverse the for loop (for(int i=SIZE-1;i>=0;i--))

```
  int size;
```

If you want to make size as argument when you called your function ,you should initialized it at SIZE(size=SIZE)

your function sum returned the sum of elemnts of array, so changed this

```
sum(array[MAX], size);//use it in void main()
```

to

```
 int k = sum(array, size);//just write the name of array without [MAX]
```

My code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 9           // i think the math one is a bit unneccessary but well

int sum(int array[], int size)
{
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    sum = sum + array[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

 int main()
{
  int array[MAX];
  printf("%d",sum(array, MAX));//here you just write the name of array without his size
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was writing my answer and I didn't see that you posted yours in the meantime. What is the code of conduct in this case, shall I delete mine since they're quite similar?

Comment: @MDXZ: If you think that your answer adds no value to a previous one, you can delete it. But this one is a code only answer, while yours contains explainations, so my advice is that you should keep it.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Sorry a lot , I make the explanations

Comment: Thanks for your fast replies guys! Your answers helped me a lot!